# Want to do spell checking in Android 2.2 

Tags: android

Want to know about any library for spell checking in android.
I have looked at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/ and jOrtho but none works in android.

Is there a way to implement spell checking in android , as i can't find any library .

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to detect each space-separated word, then check in a 'dictionary' or 'map' of words. You could check if it is a real word by looking in a file with all words, such as /usr/share/dict/words on a unix/linux system. The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker) may also help.

Comment: Currently what i'm doing in my application is..word is checked in dictionary and displayed in suggestion bar. But it is not checking/giving suggestion for ex. helo -> hello. want a spell checking like this .

Comment: That's an interesting problem. After some searching, I found this that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker

Comment: @NoBugs I have edited your comment in your answer. You can remove this.