# Making a spell check utility

Tags: data-structures, spell-checking

This idea just popped into my head, so I don't have any code to show for it, but I was curious to know the answer. How is spell check implemented on most major word processors? I'm most curious to know what kind of data structures would be used in the creation of such a utility. Also, references to algorithms would be nice answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a basic guide in python, have a look [here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

Also you might want to look at [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker)