# name spell check machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, spell-checking

I'm new to machine learning, I need to write an application which check whether a name is correct or misspelled.

Can you give me some advice where I should begin? 
Which is the best algorithm to use in this case?

Comment: this may guide you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker

Comment: One more sources : [AT&T Archive: THE UNIX Operating system](http://youtu.be/tc4ROCJYbm0) In the video, the guy showcased how to do a simple spell check program simply by gluing different small unix programs by pipes. If the problem is not huge, that is a simple way. Check that out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If checking spelling is all you need to do you can create a hash set of all the words from some freely available dictionary and then check if typed word is in the dictionary. Are there any other requirements to your task?

Comment: I have to implement :
Spelling Error Detection and
Spelling Error Correction
I may face these kind of problems :
Non-name errors
Typographical
Homophones.
The application should implement a machine learning algorithm

Comment: Then I would recommend to read the post that Zia linked to. Most relevant part to you would be this article http://stackoverflow.com/a/2294926/51260.

Additionally please take a look at [this chapter](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/dictionaries-and-tolerant-retrieval-1.html) from [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/).

Comment: Also you can watch Coursera lectures on [Natural Language Processing](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/preview/index) given by Dan Jurafsky and Chris Manning. Search for Week2 - Spelling Correction.

Comment: Do I always need to use a dictionary? Because I have to correct proper names and surnames. I should define a P(C) with the most defuse name?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the term P(C). I'd say with some algorithms it's possible to accept unknown words, proper names for example. But I wouldn't think that it's possible to suggest a correct spelling if you've never seen it.

Comment: you're helping me a lot! Thanks. However, I think I will use a data set with all English names and surnames and Damerau-Levenstein function to check the distance between two words. It may work correctly ...

Answer (score 1):

Peter Norvig and Stuart Rusell's book "Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach" would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest start with following article from [norvig spell correct](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html). It explains basic ideas behind spelling corrector with python code provided.

> What I wanted to do here is to develop, in less than a page of code, a toy spelling corrector that achieves 80 or 90% accuracy at a processing speed of at least 10 words per second.

According to this article: "The full details of an industrial-strength spell corrector are quite complex.". You may start from its references. I think whatever you implement must have better accuracy/performance than this implementation.