# How to develop a spell checker and suggester

Tags: algorithm, spell-checking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What algorithm gives suggestions in a spell checker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker)

I need to develop a Bengali spell checker and correct spell suggester. I had developed one using Edit Distance Algorithm, which does not give good prediction. Can anyone guide me to some better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter Norvig wrote a [popular article](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) on how to build a statistical spelling corrector.  If you can find a bunch of probably-correct Bengali text, the approach might work for you.  The examples are in Python, but the approach is not language specific.