# C++ Suggesting wrong spelled words

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What algorithm gives suggestions in a spell checker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker)

What algorithm should be used in a C++ program whose aim is to read from a text file and give suggestions for the wrong spelled words ?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to look into Regex.

Comment: I strongly suggest get away from regex for these tasks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance is good for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/levenshtein-distance-implementation-c/
http://murilo.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/fast-and-easy-levenshtein-distance-using-a-trie-in-c/