# How to show a list of similar user names if the given one is in database already?

Tags: database, algorithm, search, generator

> Show a user who is registering, a bunch of usernames similar to what it was entered.
>
> For example:
>
> A new user is registering. During registration, he enters his username "Rudolf", but this name is already in a database.
> So, a system should show a list of similar usernames: "Rudolf1", "Rudolf123", "Rud0lf" etc.

What can you suggest to do or to read?

Comment: You can borrow some ideas from a spell checker algorithm for starters. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker

Comment: Thank you for help. This is exactly what I was looking for.